# Using Kernel K-Means in Scikit

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, k-means

I am working with a very large dataset (1.5 Million rows) and thought about using an SVR.
Since there is so much data I though about switching to a linear SVM and using the nystroem
method to make a kernel from the uniform sampled data.

However I would rather like to construct the kernel via Kernel K-Means, but I did not find an official
implementation yet.

This link provides a unofficual method, but this results in a very large model since it is serialized.
https://tslearn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gen_modules/clustering/tslearn.clustering.KernelKMeans.html

Maybe someone has a clue where to look for this or how to implement this codewise from an arbitrary dataset?

Comment: Are you working with time series data?

Comment: No unfortunately not, I am working with housing data. I do not know if you can apply the tslearn algorithms to such data without making a mistake.